# White screen after migration to Expo

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, mobile-application

I am currently facing an issue, when running `expo start` the app shows a white blank screen once the loading is completed on both the ios simulator and device (Android has not been tested yet).

I originally started this project on the react-native CLI and recently migrated to Expo. This issue has been apparent since the migration.

I have followed a number of instructions online to try and solve this however i've had no luck. There are no errors in the console and no issues when running the JS Debug in VSC

Please find my package.json file below

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "start": "expo start",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@eva-design/eva": "^2.0.0",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^0.12.38",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.10.0",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.7.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^6.7.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^6.7.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^6.7.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.3.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.3.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.3.6",
    "@ui-kitten/components": "^5.0.0",
    "@ui-kitten/eva-icons": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^8.3.0",
    "buffer": "^5.6.0",
    "expo": "^39.0.3",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.6.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.3.3",
    "firebase": "7.9.0",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "geofirestore": "^3.4.3",
    "geofirex": "^0.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "ngeohash": "^0.6.3",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^5.6.2",
    "react-native": "^0.63.3",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-redash": "^14.1.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.7.0",
    "react-native-shared-element": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-uuid": "^1.4.9",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.14.1",
    "react-navigation-shared-element": "^5.0.0-alpha1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.24",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.62.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.8",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "16.9.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.27.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.27.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.58.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try npm install?

Comment: Hi, yes - however it did not fix the issue

Comment: Can you post your app.js

Comment: Are you using the managed or bare workflow?

Answer (score 2):

Just in case some poor soul is in a similar situation as I was, I solved it by adding `"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js"`, to my package.json. Turns out it had been removed as I migrated from a non-expo- to an expo-project.